# monkey patching an import in python before a test starts

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to write a unit-test using `pytest` and the class I'm testing is `import`ing a type for another library which open a socket during it's import. The type itself is pretty simple, it only implements `__call__` and return a plain-old-python-object that is easy to mock.

Is there a way I can monkey-patch that import so that the real python file will not get called before my test starts?

Comment: I'll try it, I'll mark it as duplicate if it is solving this issue. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mock.patch` to mock any attribute from any module.

For example, to mock the attribute name `type` from module `module1`, just add this to the top of the unittest file

```
from unittest.mock import patch
patch('module1.type')
```

Incase you like to mock that module attribute just for one testcase, use patch as a decorator

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('module1.type')
def test1(...):
    ...
```